# Air flow through a hole

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics

If I drill a hole of 1 cm diameter in each of two opposite window frames of my house, assume that the temperature outside is 0 deg C, the atmospheric pressure is 1020 millibar, wind speed is 10 meter per second against the first hole, perfect air circulation inside... what is the resulting airflow inside the house (in m3/hour) ?